# copy only filtering result to the same sheet but different columns

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I do a filtering, which is not blank and then copy the result to the column in the same sheets
however, when I paste the result if wont follow the row number, attached jped and coding for reference.

In case, I want to keep the value the the pasted column if it is blank, I can do it using for loop but its too slow as I got 200k rows and I need to do 20 columns.

```
.Range("$A$7:$" & colbcMatch & "$" & bcFinalrow).AutoFilter Field:=colnbcsd, Criteria1:="<>"
.Range(colbcSD & "7:" & colbcSD & bcFinalrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
.Range("DY7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Please notice that its only partial code, and all variables are well defined.

[image]

Comment: Why don;t you sort the column and copy paste the range instead of using filters?

Comment: what you mean is sorting the column and put the blank at last, and count how many rows in this column and paste it as if the cell is null, it wont be count? Now I use another method which is put a formula to a new column, after that copy and paste this column to a specific column.